# YouTube Speech recognition - Audio containing a special word?

Tags: audio, youtube, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm thinking about a mechanism to find out if a special word e.g. "hello world" is saying in a youtube video. I don't really know how to do this, but my approach is:

- extraction audio from youtube video via youtube-dl
- speech recognition via pocketsphinx_continuous and saving in txt file

But this is very unreliable. pocketsphinx_continuous doesn't work quite good.

Can anybody suggest a good solution to do it?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Recent pocketsphinx has special keyword spotting mode to look for keyword (pocketsphinx_kws -infile file.wav). As for being reliable, you probably didn't convert the audio to a proper format or there was other issue.

Comment: And, pocketsphinx search for keyword is way more efficient than any decoding.

Comment: I didn't find any websites explaning "pocketsphinx_kws". Only 3 pages returning from google?!

Can you explain me how I will use it?

The WAV File has proper format I think: mono, 16KHz, 16bit

Right?

Comment: Yes, it's a recent technology. Compile pocketsphinx from subversion, download en-us generic acoustic model, convert file to 16khz 16bit mono, run `pocketsphinx_kws -hmm en-us -infile file.wav -kws "key phrase"`

Answer (score 0):

`pocketsphinx_continuous` itself has kws inbuilt. 
You can use `pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm en-us -infile file.wav -dict dictfile.dict -kws "keyphrase"`